# How can I refactor two functions into one function that takes a generic argument?

Tags: elm

How can I refactor two functions into one function that has a generic parameter?

**Example:**

```
getVideo : Video -> Post
getVideo video =
    let
        (Video post) =
            video
    in
        post


getPodcast : Podcast -> Post
getPodcast podcast =
    let
        (Podcast post) =
            podcast
    in
        post
```

**I would like to do something like this:**

```
getPodcast : 'a -> Post
getPodcast 'a =
    let
        ('a post) =
            'a
    in
        post
```

**Appendix:**

```
type Video
    = Video Post

type Podcast
    = Podcast Post
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot have such an open-ended generic function in Elm. Here are two options:

1. Use a container type

You can create a container type that has a constructor for each of its valid types:

```elm
type PostContainer
    = VideoContainer Video
    | PodcastContainer Podcast
```

Now your `getPost` function consists of a `case` statement which returns the appropriate post.

```elm
getPost : PostContainer -> Post
getPost container =
    case container of
        VideoContainer (Video post) ->
            post

        PodcastContainer (Podcast post) ->
            post
```

2. Include the post type in the `Post` value

Let's say your `Post` object looks like this:

```elm
type alias Post =
    { name : String
    , body : String
    }
```

You could create an enumeration of post types like this:

```elm
type PostType = Video | Podcast
```

You could redefine `Post` to include the type:

```elm
type alias Post =
    { name : String
    , body : String
    , postType : PostType
    }
```

Or, if you choose to keep the post body separate from the type, you could do something like this:

```elm
type alias PostContents =
    { name : String
    , body : String
    }

type Post = Post PostType PostContents
```

and your `getPostContents` function would simply be

```elm
getPostContents : Post -> PostContents
getPostContents _ contents =
    contents
```